# The best practice to handle async action in redux-saga so change the screen with react-navigation based on redux reducer

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga to handle async actions like fetch data from our server.

For this purpose, I dispatch action on my screen. so I want to change navigate to another screen or show errors on the screen.

We can do this in some way like:

**Solution 1:**

For example in the login screen I do something like this:

login.js screen:

```js
// After touch login button:
onSubmit: (values) => {
  // formik on submit method
  dispatch(login({ username: values.username, password: values.password }));
},

useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && tokens && tokens.access_token && !error.status) {
      // navigate to dashboard screen
      navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
    } else if (!loading && !(tokens && tokens.access_token)
    && (error && error.code && error.code === 'some_code')) {
      // user not activated yet, so go to verification screen
      navigation.push('Verification', { username: values.username });
    }
  }, [loading, tokens, error]);
```

This method works for me but I think it's not a best practice.

**Solution 2:**
Another solution we can send a function in the screen and pass that to login action so when the saga action finished we can call that callback.

This solution is not proper for me because we should send new parameter with action payload and sent it to saga again and call it in the saga and I think it's not the best way.

```js
formSubmitted = (response) => {
const {data, status} = response;
if (status === 200) {
      // navigate to dashboard screen
      navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
    } else if (!loading && !(tokens && tokens.access_token)
    && (data.code === 'some_code')) {
      // user not activated yet, so go to verification screen
      navigation.push('Verification', { username: values.username });
    }
}

// After touch login button:
onSubmit: (values) => {
  // formik on submit method
  dispatch(login({ username: values.username, password: values.password }));
},


// saga.js
const response = yield axios.post(login, params)
// sth like this to call the callback
yield call(payload.callback, response)
```

**Solution 3:**
We can use react-navigation navigator such as this link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

But I want to hold my application concern separately and I want to navigate between screen in the screen not in the saga.

What to you think about this problem? how do you handle it?